# Include a directory with setuptools installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, setuptools, setup.py

I've made a plugin-based program that loads plugins from different directories, one of which being the directory where the module resides (for convenience of running in place inside the source repository for testing).

I'd like the plugins currently in the source repository to be installed with the module so that they will be loaded by default on any installation. This would preferably be stored inside the egg that `setup()` creates.

Currently the important parts of the source repository are as follows:

```
/path/to/repo/
    plugins/
        example.py
    myprog.py # the module
    myprog    # the script
    setup.py
```

`setup.py` looks something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'myprog',
    version = '1.0',
    scripts = ['myprog'],
    py_modules = ['myprog'],

    package_data = {
        '': ['plugins/']
    }
)
```

However, the `plugins` directory is not included with installation in any way.

How can I include it so that the line

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'plugins')
```

will properly find that directory after running `python3 setup.py install`?

Comment: add this path `sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+'/plugins')` to myprog.py or where can call ?

Comment: Don't define static path !

Comment: Adding a static path will not resolve the question. I want a file to be included in the installation. Changing the program to look in its original location is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup would break things by making a global `plugins` module that everyone would be able to import, or that everyone would import by mistake. Don’t do that.  Instead, do this:

- Make your `myprog.py` file into a package. The easiest way: `mkdir myprog; mv myprog.py myprog/__init__.py`
- Then, you can move your plugins into a subpackage. `touch plugins/__init__.py; mv plugins myprog/`
- With subpackages, you don’t have to use package data at all.
- To access your plugins, just do `import myprog.plugins.foo` for a plugin named `foo.py`.
- Also: don’t touch `__file__`, use [pkg_resources](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html) instead.
- Bonus points: [use entry points](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/) for your script.

Comment: What if the files in that directory aren't necessarily source files, such as language packs or images? How can I guarantee that directory will be included and that the module will be able to see those files using relative pathing after installation?

Comment: @2mac: at that point, you can use `package_data={'myprog': ['plugins/*'}`. Make sure to add your files to `MANIFEST.in` (google for that name).  I think `include_package_data` might work too.  (also, you need to replace `py_modules = ['myprog']` with `packages = ['myprog', 'myprog.plugins']` or use the `find_packages()` function from setuptools.

Comment: Will those be included in the installation, though? According to the documentation, `package_data` and `MANIFEST.in` only declare what to include in a source distribution. These need to be installed with the module so that they can be accessed by it as data files.

Comment: @2mac: MANIFEST.in declares files in the source distribution, package_data installs them.